# How are custom types stored in YugabyteDB YCQL?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

How are custom types [CREATE TYPE ..](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/ddl_create_type/) UDT stored in rocksdb underneath ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stored in rocksdb as a serialized map or struct.